# Oracle basic subquery

Tags: oracle

I have a question about subquery. I tried different ways however, i still can not right syntax. so please help.

I have a table like this

```
DD_Products
(
    ProductID 
    Description  
    ProductPrice 
    RetailPrice 
    LaborEST 
);
```

and try to make VIEW of list 10 products with
    highest profit(difference between sale value and cost).

so I created like this

```
CREATE VIEW Top10money_VW AS
SELECT ProductID,Money 
FROM (select *
      from DD_Products
      Order by ProductPrice - RetailPrice AS Money desc)
Where ROWNUM <= 10;
```

but it says

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE VIEW Top10money_VW AS
SELECT ProductID,Money 
FROM (select *
      from DD_Products
      Order by ProductPrice - RetailPrice AS Money desc)
Where ROWNUM <= 10

Error at Command Line:5 Column:43
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

What is correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a column called `Money` try this

```
CREATE VIEW Top10money_VW AS
SELECT ProductID,Money 
FROM (select ProductID, ProductPrice - RetailPrice Money
      from DD_Products
      Order by ProductPrice - RetailPrice desc)
Where ROWNUM <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alias directly in the order by clause if you have defined it in the select list

Please find the sample case using sqlfiddle in the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8fb0)

```
CREATE VIEW Top10money_VW AS
SELECT ProductID,Money 
FROM (select a.*,ProductPrice - RetailPrice AS Money
  from DD_Products a
  Order by Money desc)
  Where ROWNUM <= 10;
```